# Ksoap2 - sending a body with no nested tags

Tags: android, web-services, ksoap2

I need to send a soap-request that looks like this:

```
<v:Envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <v:Header/>
  <v:Body>  
  </v:Body>
</v:Envelope>
```

Right now there there are nested tags withing "body" that look like this:

```
<v:Body> 
 <d:string></d:string>  
</v:Body>
```

How can I remove them?

I am using following code to create and send the request:

```
SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "");
SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);

HttpTransportSECustom aht = new HttpTransportSECustom(HOST_NoSSL);

soapEnvelope.setAddAdornments(false);
soapEnvelope.bodyOut = "";

aht.call(SOAP_ACTION_getStatus, soapEnvelope, headers);
```

Comment: with an editor?  (IOW, not enough info to provide a useful answer)

Comment: sorry, added some more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer to my question here:
http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Output-parameters-with-ksoap2/td-p/398618/page/2